# Hiding navigation bar after showing menu on API > 24

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm stuck into a funny issue. I need to hide the navigation and status bar on my app. After several unsuccessfull trials trough layout `xml` coding I did it by code in this way:

```
private void setVisibilityOptions() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

I'm calling this into `onResume()` event handler because the Activity is derived from `AppCompatActivity` and it works.
The funny part comes when the app menu shows up. This immediatly triggers system to show-up navigation and status bar. Then if I select an item on the menu that retriggers a resume event I'm safe and status and navigation bars are hidden again, but if I do not select a menu item they stand there (with an horrible graphical effect among other things).
I tought to use `onOptionsItemSelected` event handlers but of course it's not triggered if no items is selected. `onOptionsMenuClosed` is not triggered at all.
I'm adding menu layout and toolbar section for reference:

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="xxx.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_drivers"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_drivers"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_controller"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/select_controller_title"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_map"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/map_title"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_telemetry"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/telemetry_title"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Application bar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

BTW. The main activity is derived from `AppCompatActivity` and this's not able to trigger `WindowsFocusChanged` events.
How can I fix this? 
Is it possible to catch an event when the menu closes?

Answer (score 0):

What about `onPrepareOptionsMenu`? Perharps you could call your `setVisibilityOptions()` there.

So, in theory, `onPrepareOptionsMenu` get's called,  navigation and status bar become visible, but then you call `setVisibilityOptions()` so they become invisible again and hopefully this happens too fast for the user to notice.

Comment: `onPrepareOptionsMenu` as `onMenuOpened` are triggered on menu opening not on menu closing ... I need to hide status bar and navigation when the menu is hidden .